# Definitive guide - what Azure VMs support SSD

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a guide with a definitive answer on which Azure VM types support SSD (Premium_LRS) and which support only HDD (Standard_LRS)? I can't find one.

[The only Azure docs article that talks about it that I found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/premium-storage) claims that:

> Premium Storage supports DS-series, DSv2-series, GS-series, Ls-series, and Fs-series VMs.

But then I found myself that `B-series` also supports Premium Storage and it is not mentioned here. So I am left here wondering, whether there are any more? I would love to see a list of all VM types with checkboxes next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is such a list, but the B series are relatively new, so not added to the list you provided.

The list is comprehensive as far as I can tell. All the vms with the letter `S` in name are capable of using SSD + B series.

Comment: To be fair, all VMs in B series also have `s` in them, so maybe that's their naming schema, thanks.